# Cant find code to insert into AS access database using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, oledb

I am very new to this.
I have a MS access database (.mdb having only two columns) and i have linked it using a gridview. It displays whatever is there in the database on the webpage. I also have an post button for a text box (like the one in facebook that posts status). The gridview only displays the text entered and takes auto time.
The problem is, i cannot seem to write the code that will update the database on click.
I have added a connection in web.config file.
The namespace is declared,

In the .aspx file, i have taken the sql datasource using

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Test" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB1 %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB1.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Message], [Date] FROM [DB1] order by id desc">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The code behind looks like this -

```
protected void btnpost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.******** = "INSERT INTO DB1 (message) + values ('" + txtpost.text + "')";

  gridview.databind();

  txtpost.Text="";
}
```

Can anybody tell me what goes in the '********' that does the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing part is:

```
Test.SelectCommand = "INSERT INTO DB1 (message) + values ('" + txtpost.Text + "')";
```

Comment: you need to use Capital T, like that textpost.Text

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {

       OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO DB1 (message) values (@message)");
       cmd.Connection = conn;
       conn.Open();
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@message", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtpost.Text.Trim();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Mairaj Ahmad. in the @message space, should the textbox name go there or should the database field go there? And should i add any namespace to it? Thanks in advance

Comment: You only need to change connectionstring.